# Redirect to different views from the homepage - django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm writing a django app and I would like to do something like this: in my homepage there are different options you can reach with links.

This is my homepage.html

```
<title>Homepage</title>

<body>
<li> <a href = "{% url 'options1' %} " > Options1 </a> </li>
<li> <a href = "{% url 'options2' %} " > Options2 </a> </li>
</body>
```

This my urlpatterns in "app/urls.py":

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url (r'^', view.homepage, name='homepage'),
url (r'^/options1/$', views.options1, name ='options1'),
url (r'^/options2/$', views.options2, name ='options2'),
)
```

But I can't understand how to write my view, I though to use [HttResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) (or the [shortcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)), but how to understand which Option the user choose?

This is my simply view

```
def homepage (request):

return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

When I run the app, it gives me an error, this is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'myapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/hari/project/NewSite/templates/homepage.html, error at line 8
   argument to reversed() must be a sequence

   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>



   2 : <html lang="en">



   3 : <head>



   4 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">



   5 :     <title>HomePage</title>



   6 : </head>



   7 : <body>



   8 :      <li> <a href=" {% url 'option1' %} ">Option1</a> </li>



   9 :      <li> <a href="{% url 'option2' %}">option2 </a> <li>



   10 : </body>



   11 : </html>

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/riluin/PycharmProjects/Thesis/mybper/views.py" in Homepage
  11.     return render(request, 'homepage.html')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  433.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  285.         for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):

Exception Type: TypeError at /myapp/
Exception Value: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think the homepage needs to know what option the user has chosen. Once they've clicked on the link, the home page view has nothing more to do with it: they will go straight to the view that handles the URL they clicked on.

Comment: Because when I run my app i receive this error: "Error during template rendering". Then it says to me that "argument to reversed() must be a sequence" and it highlights the {% url 'options1' %} statement

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should show it, as well as the actual view code that causes it. Note that this happens *before* you try and do any redirecting; it's an error with *displaying* the links in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is displaying the links. Now I've edited my post writing the error and the part of the code that cause the error.

Comment: No, you need to show the *full* traceback, and also the version of the view that includes the render call that actually renders that homepage template.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time, I edited the post: now there is the full traceback and the call that actually renders that homepage template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each view render a template and create an html template for each option. The Polls app from the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) is useful as a reference example.

A redirect is for when you have an old url and want links to it to point to something new. This is not what you want.

The urls each route to it's own view functions and would usually also have their own html templates. The homepage view should just handle preparing information for the homepage.

Get input data from pattern matching in urls.py. If you add

```
  (P<parameter2>.*)/
```

to the end of option2 url and change the view to

```
 def option2(request,parameter2)
```

you will get whatever is at the end before the last /.

You can also submit an HTML form and use the POST dictionary of the "request" variable. If you have a form with input fields x, y, z:

```
<form id="formxyz" action="{% url "option3" %}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="x" placeholder="x"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="y" placeholder="y"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="z" placeholder="z"/><br/>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
{% csrf_token %}</form>
```

You get the data in the request object:

```
def option3(request):
    (x,y,z) = (request.POST['x'], request.POST['y'],request.post['z'])
    txt_page = "X multiplied by Y divided by Z is "+ str((x*y)/z)+\
    repr(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse(plain_text_page,content_type="text/plain")
```

Answer (score 0):

Django provides `reverse` function, for this purpose. You can pass url name to it, and function will return url path:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def homepage (request):
    HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('option1'))
```

Also you can hardcode your url without `reverse`, just putting `/options1/` in `HttpResponseRedirect`, but better use url-name like you did.

And look at your code, you don't need this conditions about chosen option, chosen url automatically trigger view that you put in urlpaterns, like `option1` will trigger `views.options1`.

Comment: Ok, but in this way i can only redirect to the first "options1" not the second!